# Why does rsync fail with Broken pipe (32), error in socket IO (code 10) at io.c(820)?

Tags: rsync, raspbian

I bought a new hard drive for my server, and I'm trying to reorganise my files. For the first transfer, `rsync` copied ~3 GB perfectly. However, with the equivalent `rsync` command, the second transfer fails.

```
$ sudo /usr/bin/nice -n 19 /usr/bin/ionice -c2 -n7 rsync -aEHAXPx /media/a/ /media/b --delete
...
rsync: [sender] write error: Broken pipe (32)
rsync error: error in socket IO (code 10) at io.c(820) [sender=3.1.1]
```

The first run copied about 550 of 800 GB before choking. More recent attempts only manage to copy 1 GB before dying. I'm not sure if it's relevant, but the source is a [backintime](https://github.com/bit-team/backintime/) incremental backup drive, so it contains a ton of hard links. How can I fix this error and complete the command?

I'm running rsync  version 3.1.1  protocol version 31.

Comment: anything in dmesg ? (I have had rsync killed by the kernel for memory consumption before)

Comment: @user1133275 Huh, didn't think to look there. `[85852.560086] Out of memory: Kill process 4242 (rsync) score 194 or sacrifice child
[85852.562695] Killed process 4243 (rsync) total-vm:121948kB, anon-rss:65752kB, file-rss:4kB`

Comment: Please vote to close. I'm unable to reproduce this any more, because I solved the problem in other ways. (See comment to the answer.)

Answer (score 5):

```
dmesg | grep rsync
```

> [85852.560086] Out of memory: Kill process 4242 (rsync) score 194 or sacrifice child [85852.562695] Killed process 4243 (rsync) total-vm:121948kB, anon-rss:65752kB, file-rss:4kB – Sparhawk

solutions:

- change your rsync speed to below that of your disks.`--bwlimit=6000` .. USB 2 is 60MB/s /4 for rw over 2 drives or /10 for seeking on non ssd... or get a XU4 with 2GB RAM and USB3.
- change the kernel memory parameters `echo 100 > /proc/sys/vm/watermark_scale_factor`
- force a memory purge during operation `echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`
- make sure you are using kernel 4.9.29 `uname -r`

Comment: Thanks (+1), I'll give the first solution a go and report back. My kernel is `4.4.35-v7+`, but that's just what is provided by Raspbian :/.

Comment: @Sparhawk yes the first option will likely fix the issue, side note: 4.4.70 is the latest for that branch, I'm not sure why it has not made it to the apt mirrors yet but if you want to try other kernels https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/kernel/updating.md and https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/tree/rpi-4.9.y

Comment: Oops I forgot about `rpi-update`. I just ran it and now I'm on `4.9.29-v7+`. Were you suggesting that this might be adequate to fix the error?

Comment: I just tried again on the new kernel, and got the same error. I'll try limiting to 6000 now.

Comment: @Sparhawk it has happened that memory management in the kernel was change to be less than ideal for low memory boards, but clearly in this case rsync is unstable on the last 35 kernel fix sets. so yah try bwlimit.

Comment: Oh man. That was a rollercoaster. So the new kernel was… problematic for me. I had constant freezes, `/var/log/messages` reported `swapper/0: page allocation failure`, `Out of memory: Kill process 6271 (foo)`, and `bar invoked oom-killer`. I tried enabling `smsc95xx.turbo_mode=N` and `vm.min_free_kbytes = 32768`, but nothing helped. Then my system refused to boot, and I could detect bad blocks on the SD card. It was possibly unrelated, but I was too paranoid to upgrade to the new kernel again. I had to restore from backups, and since my system was down anyway, I just did the `rsync` offline…

Comment: Thank you again for your help, but I'm just going to close this question, because I'm not in a position to test any answers any more. Cheers.